# Block cell from executing in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I have a piece of code in a cell of my ipython notebook that takes a while when it gets executed. Is there a possibility to block a cell explicitly once you ran it so that it doesn't get executed when you run it a second time?

I have had a few times when i accidentally ran a cell a second time and i had to wait for the outcome before i can proceed with the next steps in my notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either comment the cell out by using `Ctrl + /`.

Or have a look at the [ipycache module](https://github.com/rossant/ipycache). It allows to store the calculations in a file and when you execute the cell a second time it simply loads the result from the file.

Usage:

```
%%cache mycache.pkl var1 
var1 = some_lengthy_calculation()
```